# Сохранить текст из RichTextBox в файл

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

При срабатывании свойства `Form1_FormClosing` текст из `RichTextBox` должен сохраниться в формате rtf в папку с проектом. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно подписаться на событие `Form1_FormClosing`:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SaveFile("richtext1.rtf");
}
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы сохранялось только тогда когда есть текст в RichTextBox?

Comment: Поставьте в начале условие: `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(richTextBox1.Text))`

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void SaveMyFile()
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
        saveFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";

        if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() ==DialogResult.OK && saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Без SaveFileDialog. Файл сам должен сохраниться.

Comment: @Fanning, "сам должен сохраниться" - это вообще топ условие. Само по себе ничего не произойдет, вызывайте эту функцию когда нужно сохранить текст в файл.

Comment: Неужели нельзя сделать без OpenFileDialog? Чтобы при закрытии программы текст сохранился в файл без запроса куда сохранить. Что-то вроде кэша.